# Where can I find a map of Ice Age Berengia?

Tags: prehistory, maps

I need your help to find out more information about how to find map that is relate  about Ice Age mammoth hunters who lived on Beringia, the ancient land bridge that inter-connected Alaska and Siberia that prehistoric Asian people crossed into North America as ancestors of the Native peoples of the Americas

I have a friend that has his draw hand paper map that he would like me to do digitize it into ArcGIS Pro. I am going to have to scan it and georeference it and overlay where it is and into black and white map for his historical fiction novel book ?

Is there a map that can you point me and it is to help me to take a look at the map and their local names for that area ? Do you have a suggest for me to find it.  I am not really familiar with this but yes I am aware of the history that the Native American that came across the Beringia sea ?

Comment: The (at present 6) maps on the [Wikipedia page for Beringia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beringia) don't do it for you?